# Regex - I need to split a string after the first number

Tags: javascript, regex

Strings:

```
-45
89
-ertu567
tree5678
```

I need those to split like this:

```
-4       5
8        9
-ertu5   67
tree5    678
```

Everytime I try to use `\d`, it sees the `-` as a digit.

Comment: @tzunghaor please don't confuse others, those two things are synonymous here.

Comment: @Ja͢ck They are not. [0-9] is simply 0-9 whereas \d can contain any unicode number.

Comment: @Forlan07 Not in JavaScript. In JS `\d` is a shorthand for `[0-9]`.

Comment: I currently have nothing that gets close to working, but Forlan07 below has posted ^.*?[0-9], which gets me the second half of the string, but is not giving me the first half as an array output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works with me

```
/^(\D*\d)(.*)$/
```

I made a fiddle for you to see and to play with

https://regex101.com/r/xW4aE8/1

Comment: This is it, you win!!! Thanks a ton gijswijs

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the index of a regex match, and split the string after that index:

```js
function splitAtDigit(str) {
  var m = /\d/.exec(str);
  return m ? [str.substr(0, m.index + 1), str.substr(m.index + 1)] : [str];
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(splitAtDigit("-ertu567")));
```

Comment: This is far too complicated, is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. @gijswijs' solution is simpler.